# Arrow marker in IE are not rendered correct

Tags: reactjs, svg

I need to render lines with different line width and arrow sizes in SVG using react. While all browsers renders the arrow heads correct, the IE seems to render them way to large.

```
<svg>
      <defs>
        {[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map((size, index) => (
          <marker
            id={`arrowHead-${index}`}
            key={index}
            markerWidth={size * 2}
            markerHeight={size * 2}
            viewBox="0 0 10 10"
            refX="5"
            refY="5"
            orient="auto"
            markerUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
          >
            <path d="M 0 0 L 10 5 L 0 10z" fill="lime" strokeDasharray="0" />
          </marker>
        ))}
      </defs>
      <g>
        {[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].map((size, index) => (
          <line
            x1={10 + index * 30}
            y1={0}
            x2={10 + index * 30}
            y2={100}
            stroke="lime"
            strokeWidth={size}
            style={{ markerEnd: `url('#arrowHead-${index}')` }}
          />
        ))}
      </g>
    </svg>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pw3x8qw0lq) is a running example

Comment: The codesandbox link doesn't seem to work in IE.  Or did you mean Edge?

Comment: could you try this url: https://pw3x8qw0lq.codesandbox.io/

Comment: IE has a bug where it takes the stroke of the line you attach the markers to, and draws it on the marker as well. The fix is to add `stroke="none"` to the marker path(s).

Comment: @PaulLeBeau turns out it was quite more complicated. A coworker of mine found out the real issues with is, that `path` in the `marker` get styles that were defined for the path it self without anyway to overwrite it. Have a look at this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6nv9yjw45n. Would be nice to reopen the question so I can post the correct answer. There is also already an issue for this: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10321915/

Comment: Your main question about why the markers appear too big is answered by the linked question.  Your additional info seems more like a separate marker bug that is related but not directly applicable.  So I don't think this question needs to be reopened.  I would encourage you to ask (and answer) a new question about this new issue if you want. Assuming there isn't one already.